# How can we generate reports for Gatling run when it gets crash or hard stop

Tags: gatling

How can we generate reports for Gatling run when it gets crash or hard stop?

I am running the Gatling test for 4 hours and if the test is getting failed or if I am doing ctrl+c then reports are not generated, do we have any ways to generate from stopped Gatling run (has simulation.log)

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/general/reports/): use the `-ro` option.